# CREATING A POPUP MESSAGE AFTER CLICKING SUBMIT BUTTON

Tags: html

ACTUALLY I WANT TO CREATE A HTML PAGE WITH FEW TEXTFIELDS LIKE ACCOUNT NUMBER AND SUBMIT BUTTON AND AFTER CLICKING IN THE SUBMIT BUTTON IT HAS TO SHOW A POPUP ASKING FOR YOUR CONFIRMATION.I HAVE ALREADY CREATED A WEB PAGE BUT DONT KNOW HOW TO CREATE A POPUP MESSAGE.COULD YOU PLEASE COME UP WITH A CODE

Comment: Define "a popup message".  If you want to perform some kind of logic in code on your page then what you're looking for are introductory tutorials on JavaScript.

Comment: All caps = instant downvote

Comment: FIX YOUR BROKEN **CAPS LOCK** KEY !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript's `alert("message");` function in between `<script>` tags on your html page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use confirm method in javascript to show the pop up .

```
confirm("message");//for confirm you should have to click ok to do other things
alert("message");//it will alert whatever inside .
```

read about [confirm() here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `onclick=myMethod()` attribute to your button, and use the `confirm()` method in JavaScript, which returns `true` if the user clicks OK and `false` if they click cancel.

[Here is the w3schools page for the `confirm()` method, which should help you out.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

It's worth pointing out that just HTML will not let you respond to their data, by the way.
Hope this helps!